# Dynamic matrix multiplication without loops

Tags: arrays, r, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm stuck with the following problem:

---

Suppose that I have three pairs of sequences:

`{a_1, ..., a_N}, {A_1, ..., A_T}, {b_1, ..., b_N}, {B_1, ..., B_T}, {c_1, ..., c_N}, {C_1, ..., C_T}`.

My aim is to perform the following action (without looping!):

```
for (i in 1:N) {
  for (j in 1:N) {
    for (k in 1:N) {
      ret[i,j,k] <- \sum_{t=1}^T (a_i - A_t) * (b_j - B_t) * (c_k - C_t)
}}}
```

The reason why I don't want to loop is that there might be more pairs of sequences than simply those three. And I want to structure the code as "efficiently and flexible" as possible.

If we only have two pairs of sequences, then the problem is quite easy since it reduces to simple matrix multiplication (an `(N x T)` matrix for `(a_i - A_t)` and an `(N x T)` matrix for `(b_i - B_t)` where you multiply the first with the transpose of the second).

But once you have more than two pairs of sequences, I'm not sure whether it can be done without loops since the dimensionality of `output` depends on the number of pairs of sequences...

---

------------------------------------------ Related problem (Nov. 8th, 2013) ------------------------------------------

I got the first part successfully implemented thanks to **@-mrip**. But how would the code have to be altered if I want the following:

```
for (i in 1:N) {
  for (j in 1:N) {
    for (k in 1:N) {
      ret[i,j,k] <- \sum_{t=1}^T foo(a_i, a_i - A_t) * foo(b_j, b_j - B_t) * foo(c_k, c_k - C_t)
}}}
```

Where `foo(a, a-A)` is some common bivariate function. Is there a "general" solution, or do you need more information about the structure of `foo(a, a-A)`?

I tried it using the straightforward solution and simply implement the loops. Of course this is neither flexible (since I have to restrict myself in advance to the possible number of pairs/dimensions) nor fast (since both `a` and `A` can be large - although it might be the case that `a` is simply a scalar and `A` some set of observations).

I know that I might be demanding. But I' m totally stuck on this problem since quite some time... Hence any help is extremely welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This actually doesn't require any matrix multiplication at all.  It only requires taking outer products, and the final result can be put together efficiently and concisely exploiting the column-major layout of R matrices and multidimensional arrays.  The computation can be made more efficient by expanding out the product in the loop into individual summands.  This leads to the following implementation.

```
 vecout<-function(...)as.vector(outer(...))

 f2<-function(a,b,c,A,B,C){
 N<-length(a)
 t<-length(A)

 ab<-vecout(a,b)
 ret<-array(vecout(ab,c),c(N,N,N))*t

 ret<-ret - ab * sum(C)
 ret<-ret - vecout(a,rep(c,each = N)) * sum(B)
 ret<-ret - rep(vecout(b,c) * sum(A),each=N)
 ret<-ret + a * sum(B*C)
 ret<-ret + rep(b * sum(A*C),each=N)
 ret<-ret + rep(c * sum(A*B),each=N^2)
 ret<-ret - sum(A*B*C)
 ret
 }
```

We can compare the running time and check the correctness as follows.  Here is the naive implementation:

```
f1<-function(a,b,c,A,B,C){
 N<-length(a)
 ret<-array(0,c(N,N,N))
 for(i in 1:N)
  for(j in 1:N)
   for(k in 1:N)
    ret[i,j,k]<-sum((a[i]-A)*(b[j]-B)*(c[k]-C))
 ret
 }
```

Te optimized version runs substantially faster and produces the same result, up to numerical precision error:

```
> a<-rnorm(100)
> b<-rnorm(100)
> c<-rnorm(100)
> A<-rnorm(200)
> B<-rnorm(200)
> C<-rnorm(200)
> system.time(r1<-f1(a,b,c,A,B,C))
   user  system elapsed 
  9.006   1.125  10.204 
> system.time(r2<-f2(a,b,c,A,B,C))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.203   0.033   0.242 
> max(abs(r1-r2))
[1] 1.364242e-12
```

If you have more than three sequences each, the same idea will work.  It shouldn't be too hard to code up the general solution, in fact, it might well be possible to write the general solution with less lines of code than the hard-coded 3 sequence solution, although it will take a little thought to get all of the index manipulations just right.

On edit:  OK, couldn't resist.  Here's a general solution, with an arbitrary number of pairs, passed as the columns of two matrices:

```
f3<-function(a,A){
  subsets<-as.matrix(expand.grid(rep(list(c(F,T)),ncol(a))))
  ret<-array(0,rep(nrow(a),ncol(a)))

  for(i in 1:nrow(subsets)){
    sub<-as.logical(subsets[i,])
    temp<-Reduce(outer,as.list(data.frame(a[,sub,drop=F])),init=1)
    temp<-temp*sum(apply(A[,!sub,drop=F],1,prod))
    temp<-aperm(array(temp,dim(ret)),order(c(which(sub),which(!sub))))
    ret<-ret+temp*(-1)^(sum(!sub))
  } 
  ret
}

> system.time(r3<-f3(cbind(a,b,c),cbind(A,B,C)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.258   0.056   0.303 
> max(abs(r3-r1))
[1] 9.094947e-13
```

---------------------  Edit again (Nov 8 2013) ---------------------

The answer give above is the most efficient when the arrays `A`, `B`, and `C` are large.  If `A`, `B`, and `C` are much smaller than `a`, `b`, and `c`, then here is an alternate, more concise solution:

```
f4<-function(a,A){
  ret<-array(0,rep(nrow(a),ncol(a)))
  for(i in 1:nrow(A)){
    temp<- Reduce(outer,as.list(data.frame(a-rep(A[i,],each=nrow(a)))),init=1)
    ret<-ret + as.vector(temp )
  }
  ret
}
```

In the above setup, where `a`, `b`, `c`, have length `100` and `A`, `B`, `C` have length `200`, this is slower than the other solution:

```
> system.time(r3<-f3(cbind(a,b,c),cbind(A,B,C)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.704   0.092   0.256 
> system.time(r4<-f4(cbind(a,b,c),cbind(A,B,C)))
   user  system elapsed 
 65.824  19.060   3.553 
> max(abs(r3-r4))
[1] 2.728484e-12
```

However, if `A`, `B`, and `C` have length `1`, then it is much faster:

```
> A<-rnorm(1)
> B<-rnorm(1)
> C<-rnorm(1)
> system.time(r3<-f3(cbind(a,b,c),cbind(A,B,C)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.796   0.172   0.222 
> system.time(r4<-f4(cbind(a,b,c),cbind(A,B,C)))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.180   0.012   0.017 
> max(abs(r3-r4))
[1] 7.105427e-15
```

Comment: Hi mrip. Thank you very much for your comment. It seems exactly what I've been looking for. You even spotted my typo in the loop: loop from 1 to N, and not 1 to T! I'll check later whether it suits my needs and will come back to you asap. In the meantime: Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi @mrip, I have **another question** to ask. I tried to understand your code as good as I can. But now I'm stuck with another problem... When I want to structure to code for the case that A=B=C=0. Then obviously the only case that is left is `subsets = T T T` and some parts of the code drop out. But what is the purpose of `sum(apply(A[,!sub,drop=F],1,prod))`?

Comment: See the edit for an alternate implementation which is better if `A=B=C=0`.  The purpose of `sum(apply(A[,!sub,drop=F],1,prod))` is to get the product of the terms that are not part of the product of lower case `a`.  Basically, the original solution (`f3`) expands the product into a bunch of individual additive terms, and computes each one individually, whereas `f4` does the subtraction first and then the outer produce.  Which is more efficient depends on the sizes of the inputs.

Comment: Thank you @mrip. Indeed, `f4` is more intuitive (at least for me). As you perfectly wrote, unfortunately it becomes "slow" once you increase the size of `a`, `b`, `c`, `A`, `B` and `C` - which is potentially the case for my usage... If you have some time and nerves left, please consider my complicated extension. Have a nice evening!

Comment: Re: your extension.  A variation of `f4` should work, provided that your function `foo` is vectorized correctly.  Whether a faster version like `f3` is possible will depend on `foo`, since it relies on algebraic expansion into individual terms.